# open() method not found in FSDirectory in Lucene search

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to implement lucene full text search in my website. but i am FSDirectory not supporting open(file) method.I am getting error **The method open(File) is undefined for the type FSDirectory**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code :

try{
   Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
   SimpleAnalyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();

IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new

IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_35, analyzer);

IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(indexDir), indexWriterConfig);

System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + indexDir + "'...");
   int indexedDocumentCount = indexer.indexDocs(indexWriter, conn);

indexWriter.close();

System.out.println(indexedDocumentCount + " records have been indexed successfully");

} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();